# Does having ext.js installed locally affect how ext.js apps run in your browser

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm developing in ext.js and I'm seeing some really weird behavior.

We have 2 QA guys see a page one way while another developer and I see it another way.  The actual markup of the page is slightly different.

We've done multiple screensharing sessions to confirm that we're doing everything the same as the QA guys.  We have tried Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.  We've both tried clearing browser cache, and even logging in with each other's credentials, but all of the browsers on my dev machine see the page with slightly different markup than the QA people.

This is when we're viewing a webpage that's running on a test server, not running on our local dev machines.

I'm wondering if that fact that the other developer and I have ext.js installed on our machines could mean that we're running a slightly different version of ext.js when we view the app that's running on the test server than what the 2 qa guys see.

Comment: I've found 2 other devs here who see the page the way it appears to the QA guys.  Both myself and other dev who sees the page the way it appears to the QA guys did a sencha upgrade and so we're both on the same sencha version, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the same build (dev/prod) command? Also, is it available as a npm application?

Where's the markup differ?